# Read and write via Object Stream

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have a client/server connected over socket.
the client writes integer value to be read by the server
I use `readInt()` in `ObjectOutputStream` to write this value
and in the server side I use `readInt()` in `ObjectInputStream` to read this value.
But the server doesn't read any anything, it freeze at `readInt()`
What problem in reading using `ObjectInputStream`?
I was used `DataOutputStream`, and reading and writing was successful, but `ObjectInputstream` can read integer and other primitive type, what is the problem?

```
public class Server {
ServerSocket listener;
private static final int PORT = 9001;
private Socket socket;
private ObjectInputStream obin = null;
private ObjectOutputStream obout = null;
public Server() throws Exception{
    listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    run();
}
public void run() throws Exception{
    socket = listener.accept();
    obout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    obout.flush();
    obin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    int h=obin.readInt();
    System.out.println(h);
    obout.writeInt(77); 
}
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server s = new Server();
    }
 }
```

and the client

```
public class Client {
 private ObjectInputStream oin = null;
 private ObjectOutputStream oot = null;
 private Socket socket = null;
 public Client() throws Exception{
    String serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
    oot = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oot.flush();
    oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    oot.writeInt(66);
    int u = oin.readInt();
    System.out.println(u);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Client c= new Client();
}
}
```

When you run this code is supposed to get at the server 66
and at the client 77,
But actually I do not get anything.   Why?

Comment: Why are you flushing the outputstream before writing and not after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every write you should flush() as it clears the output buffer which sends the bytes over the network. So your Server run method should be:

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    socket = listener.accept();

    obin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    int h = obin.readInt();
    System.out.println(h);

    obout = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    obout.writeInt(77);
    obout.flush();
}
```

and your Client constructor:

```
public Client() throws Exception {
    String serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);

    oot = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    oot.writeInt(66);
    oot.flush();

    oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    int u = oin.readInt();
    System.out.println(u);
}
```

If you're doing this as an exercise it's fine, but if you're going to run code based on this in production consider using higher level network libraries like [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).